# How to run nginx and gunicorn in same docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a python flask application with gunicorn and nginx . I am trying to run both gunicorn(wsgi) and nginx in same container . But my nginx is not started . By login into container I am able to start nginx.
Below is my dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install \
    nginx \
    python3-dev \
    curl \
    vim \
    build-essential \
    procps

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY nginx-conf  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["bash" , "server.sh"]
```

server.sh file looks like

```
# turn on bash's job control
set -m

gunicorn  --bind  :8000  --workers 3 wsgi:app
service nginx start or /etc/init.d/nginx
```

gunicorn is started by server.sh but nginx is not started.

My aim is to later run these containers in kubernetes. Should  i) I run both nginx and gunicorn in separate pod or ii) run it in same pod with separate container or iii) run in same container in same pod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My aim is to later run these containers in kubernetes. Should i) I run both nginx and gunicorn in separate pod

Yes, this.  This is very straightforward to set up (considering YAML files with dozens of lines "straightforward"): write a Deployment and a matching (ClusterIP-type) Service for the GUnicorn backend, and then write a separate Deployment and matching (NodePort- or LoadBalancer-type) Service for the Nginx proxy.  In the Nginx configuration, use a `proxy_pass` directive, pointing at the name of the GUnicorn Service as the backend host name.

There's a couple of advantages to doing this.  If the Python service fails for whatever reason, you don't have to restart the Nginx proxy as well.  If you're handling enough load that you need to scale up the application, you can run a minimum number of lightweight Nginx proxies (maybe 3 for redundancy) with a larger number of backends depending on the load.  If you update the application, Kubernetes will delete and recreate the Deployment-managed Pods for you, and again, using a separate Deployment for the proxies and backends means you won't have to restart the proxies if only the application code changes.

So, to address the first part of the question:

> I am trying to deploy a python flask application with gunicorn and nginx.

In plain Docker, for similar reasons, you can run two separate containers.  You could manage this in Docker Compose, which has a much simpler YAML file layout; it would look something like

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: . # Dockerfile just installs GUnicorn, CMD starts it
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d # could build a custom image too
        # configuration specifies `proxy_pass http://backend:8000`
    ports:
      - '8888:80'
```

This sidesteps all of the trouble of trying to get multiple processes running in the same container.  You can simplify the Dockerfile you show:

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
    python3-dev \
    build-essential
# (don't install irrelevant packages like vim or procps)
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
# (don't need a shell script wrapper)
CMD gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 wsgi:app
```

Comment: great answer. you are missing a RUN directive on line BTW :)

Comment: I was missing a backslash; fixed.  (For layer-caching reasons it's important to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single `RUN` command.)

Comment: ah ok, gotcha, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

About choosing how to split containers between pods, that really depends on the use-case. If they talk to each other but perform separate tasks, I would go with two containers and one pod.

Also, about your server.sh file, the reason gunicorn starts but nginx doesn't is that gunicorn doesn't run in daemon mode by default. If you run `gunicorn --help` you see this:

```
  -D, --daemon          Daemonize the Gunicorn process. [False]
```

I still think it's better to separate the containers but if you want it to just work, change it to this:

```
# turn on bash's job control
set -m

gunicorn  --bind  :8000  --workers 3 wsgi:app -D
service nginx start or /etc/init.d/nginx
```

Comment: if I run gunicorn  --bind  :8000  --workers 3 wsgi:app -D . docker container does not start

Comment: Same file or multiple docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question regarding Kubernetes:

It depends on what you want to do.

Containers within the same Pod share the same [network namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html), meaning that 2 containers in the same Pod can communicate with each other by contacting `localhost`. This means your packages never get send around and communication is always gonna be possible.

If you split them up into separate Pods you will want to create a [Service object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and let them communicate via that Service object. Having them in two Pods allows you to scale them up and down individually and overall gives you more options to configure them individually, for example by setting different kind of security mechanisms.

Which option you choose depends on your architecture and what you want to accomplish.
Having two containers in the same Pod is usually only done when it follows a "Sidecar" pattern, which basically means that there is a "main" container doing the work and the others in the Pod simply assist the "main" container and have no reason whatsoever to exist on their own.